# string manipulation, insert a string just right before a number

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I have this string.

```
"Remote Control 14.12, Foo Bar 41.2, Wooden Chair 83.13"
```

And I want to make it

```
"Remote Control - 14.12, Foo Bar - 41.2, Wooden Chair - 83.13"
```

Tried chaining regex but I can find a way to insert in the middle. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to [learn some regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info) before attempting to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a job for a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): Match and replace a space if it's followed by a digit:

```
result = subject.replace(/ (?=\d)/g, " - ");
```

**Explanation:**

```
/ (?=\d)/g
^^^     ^^
|||     ||
|||     |Find all matches (not just the first one)
|||     End of regex
||Assert that the next character is a digit
|Match a space
Start of regex
```

If you also want to insert a dash *after* a number (but not at the end of the string), you have to do it in a separate step because of JavaScript's lamentable lack of support for lookbehind assertion:

```
final_result = result.replace(/, /g, " - ");
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to read that regex? It would be helpful in my part.

Comment: I see. How bout turning the string into this "Remote Control - 14.12 - Foo Bar - 41.2 - Wooden Chair - 83.13" I'm still learning the way of regex works.

Comment: You need to do that in a separate step because JavaScript only supports lookahead, not lookbehind (which you'd need to check if the *previous*  character is a digit).

Comment: Like this? `str.replace(/ (?=\d)/g, " - ").replace(/, /g, ' - ')` will that do?

Answer (score 1):

Without lookahead you can use this regex:

```
var s = "Remote Control 14.12, Foo Bar 41.2, Wooden Chair 83.13";
var r = s.replace(/( \d)/g, " -$1");
//=> "Remote Control - 14.12, Foo Bar - 41.2, Wooden Chair - 83.13"
```

**Search for:**

```
1st Capturing group ( \d) - capture this string into `$1` where
  matches the character " " (space) literally
  \d match a digit [0-9]
```

**Replace with:**

```
 " -$1" which is space followed by hyphen followed by $1 (back reference to string captured)
```

Comment: Wow. That's amazing. Can you tell me why'd you put parenthesis for metacharacters and how to read that regex? and What is the dollar sign for?

Comment: Added some explanation.

Comment: I see. How bout turning the string into this "Remote Control - 14.12 - Foo Bar - 41.2 - Wooden Chair - 83.13" I'm still learning the way of regex works.